# Sqlite Timestamp (String) to epoch?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the Timestamp (string - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) column converted to millis (unix/epoch) for simple comparison against `System.currentTimeMillis()` - there are a million tutorials for converting epoch time to human readable format - not so much going the other way.

Worst case, I'll write a conversion from sqlite, but I prefer to use Java.

Thanks!

Comment: `Long.parseLong(String s)`?

Comment: Clever - unfortunately it fails. The format of the SQLite `TIMESTAMP` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String sample = "2014-06-27 11:22:33";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.US );
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition( 0 );
Date dt = sdf.parse( sample, pp );
if( dt != null )
    Log.i( "Parsed: ", String.valueOf( dt.getTime() ) );
```

Comment: There is always some hidden method needed to do something,learned only from an example - in this case, `ParsePosition` - that is absent from the related docs (Date, DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat, Calendar, etc). Thanks for the help @323go